# How to abort currently running build automatically when new one is in queue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Build A is in progress. Build B is in the queue. How to (automatically/programmatically) set the build B and like B to cancel currently running build?

Yes this is quiet period like question, but the idea is to cancel the currently running job and execute only the last one.

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760716/jenkins-abort-running-build-if-new-one-is-started.