# How to cancel a running Jenkins pipeline in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to cancel a running pipeline once a new job instance is triggered.

Found [Here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#setResult-java.lang.String-) that `setResult('FAILURE')` might do the trick.

But seems not possible as generated the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: can only set the result property on the current build
```

Here is a snipped I am using:

```
    stage('Cancel running job') {
        steps {
                script {
                    def buildToCancel 
                    buildToCancel = currentBuild.getPreviousBuildInProgress()
                    buildToCancel.setResult('FAILURE') 
                }
        }
    }
```

And yet, cancelling a job from Jenkins UI is possible, so question is how to make it done from a jenkinsfile.

Comment: Maybe try [doStop()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#doStop--) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the milestone step. Sounds like it's what you are trying to achieve.

> By default, Pipeline builds can run concurrently. The milestone step
> ensures an older build will not override a newer build, so the older
> build will never be allowed to pass a milestone (it is aborted) if a
> newer build already passed it.

See: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-milestone-step/

Comment: As i understand, milestone step used for multibranch pipelines.
I Used midn's answer from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760716/jenkins-abort-running-build-if-new-one-is-started